# How to check if a numeric value is an integer?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to check if a value is an integer in Python. Note that by integer I mean values like `2`, `1.0` and `-4.0000`, whereas `0.4` and `-2.3` are not integers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Also, `float(obj) == int(float(obj))`

Comment: When someone votes to close, there's a comment as to why. In this case, there appears to be another post which already answers your question. Check it out

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Oh... I missed that because the most accepted and upvoted answer there only tells you if `value` is of *type* `int`, which is not what I want (I accept `1.0` as an integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` instances have an `is_integer` method, which tells you whether `f == int(f)`. The following snippet will therefore work for both integers and floats, as well as any strings representing either of those numerical types:

```
float(value).is_integer()
```