# How to check if result is integer in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

I have simple task to count number, for example:

```
a = 7
b = 9
result = 0

for _ in (0:100):
     result = a / b
     b += 1
```

How I can stop the for loop when result is an integer?

Checking if method is_integer() wasn't meet my expectations.

I have to use Python 2.6

Comment: Try using `while` instead `for` loop

Comment: @Arman `while` is lowercase

Comment: I hope yoiu know the above code is not even syntactically valid - the for statement in Python always iterate through sequences - if you want a numeric for loop, the usueal thing to do is to use the built-in `range` function - thus: `for _ in range(0, 100):` is a valid way to do it.

Comment: In Python 2.x, the normal division is constrained to integer results by default - so you probably have problems very soon. You can, on the first line of your program, write the statement `from __future__ import division`  so that the result of an integer division can be a float.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. On Stack Overflow, you mark a problem as resolved by accepting an answer. If none of the answers is completely satisfying, feel free to post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `% 1`. Modular arithmetic returns the remainder, so if you try to divide by 1 and the remainder is 0, it must be an integer.

```
if result % 1 == 0:
    print "result is an integer!"
```

**OR** use the method mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682047/2773311) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952377/2773311):

```
if result.is_integer():
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use:

```
while result % 1 != 0:
```

to make the loop repeat until you get an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python 2.6 you could use:

```
isinstance(result, (int, long))
```

to check if your result is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the type method:

```
if type(a/b) == int:
    break
```

You could also use the while loop approach as suggested by other answers:

```
   while type(a/b) != int:
       # your code
```

Comment: Please note that in common cases from Python 3.x upwards, the / operator always yields an integer. This test will not work. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/why-does-integer-division-yield-a-float-instead-of-another-integer